# PyGeodesy package not opening PGM file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pygeodesy

I am trying to evaluate geoid heights using Earth Gravitational Models. I use the following script: ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564727/evaluating-geoid-heights-using-egms-in-python))

```
# geoid.py
from pygeodesy import GeoidKarney
from pygeodesy.ellipsoidalKarney import LatLon

ginterpolator = GeoidKarney("C:/Users/user/Desktop/geoids/egm2008-5.pgm")

point = LatLon(51.416422, -116.217151)
h = ginterpolator(point)
print(f"heigth: {h}")
```

Geoid model (PGM file) is [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geographiclib/files/geoids-distrib/egm2008-5.zip) for egm2008-5.

It works in command prompt.

```
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python.exe "C:\Users\user\Desktop\geoid.py"
# heigth: -11.977289233865054
```

But when I use the script in QGIS Python Editor, it gives this error in line `ginterpolator = ...`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pygeodesy\geoids.py", line 934, in __init__
    self._pgm = p = _PGM(g, pgm=egm_pgm, itemsize=self.u2B, sizeB=self.sizeB)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pygeodesy\geoids.py", line 1455, in __init__
    raise self._Errorf(_format_, 'Attr', t)

pygeodesy.geoids.PGMError: Attr b'Geoid file in PGM format for the GeographicLib::Geoid class'
  in 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/geoids/egm2008-5.pgm', invalid
```

```
QGIS version: 3.24.3-Tisler
QGIS code revision: cf22b74e
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
OS version: Windows 10 Version 2009
```

The same error occurs in Ubuntu 20.04.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you share your *.pgm* file ?

Comment: @ Taras I've added a link.

Comment: Looks like ["Issue parsing or cropping an egm*.pgm geoid dataset."](https://mrjean1.github.io/PyGeodesy/docs/pygeodesy.geoids.PGMError-class.html)

Comment: @Taras I am aware of that. I just cannot understand why it works in command prompt and it doesn't work in QGIS. What could be causing this error?